# Run PowerShell script from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a requirement to run a PS file from C#. PS1 file content is `$ADStatus=Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Server "xyz.com";`.

When I run this PS file from C# I get the following error, however when running the same PS file from a PowerShell window it runs fine. What should I do?

> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException , System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Test-ComputerSecureChannel' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

I am using package **Microsoft.Powershell.SDK v7.1.5**.
C# code:

```cs
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create(string scriptFilePath))
    {
        var result = ps.Invoke();
    
        var results = ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(scriptFilePath)).Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: please show the content of your ps1 file e.g. `scriptFilePath`

Comment: @Avshalom, PS1 content is `$ADStatus=Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Server "xyz.com";`

Comment: It does not look like `Test-ComputerSecureChannel` is available in PSCore.  Try using the PowerShell 5.1 packages.  You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/?view=powershell-7.1) it is not listed, but it is listed on the 5.1 list

Comment: @AndrewMorton, i tried running VS with admin but no luck.

Comment: @Daniel, i am trying it

Comment: @Daniel, do you know of any Powershell 5.1 package?

Comment: You need to use the Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies package instead of the Microsoft.Powershell.SDK v7.1.5

Comment: Ok. let me try it.

Comment: One other thing, your project should be .NET Framework and not .NET Core

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238748/discussion-between-pankaj-and-daniel).